# ASP.NET WebForms FriendlyUrlSegments does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: webforms, friendly-url, asp.net-4.5

I'm doing a simple test with FriendlyUrls in ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms, Foo.aspx becomes /Foo/ (it works).
When I try to use FriendlyUrlSegments Attribute to get the id from URL into the control I get this error:

```
'Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.ModelBinding.FriendlyUrlSegmentsAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

method that has the [FriendlyUrlSegments] error:

```
public Person GetPerson([FriendlyUrlSegments]int? id)
{
    return People.Find(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

I have tried to update FriendlyUrls from NuGet.

Answer (score 2):

Write your method like so:

```
public Person GetPerson([FriendlyUrlSegments(0)] int? id)
{
    return People.Find(p => p.Id == id);
}
```

The `[FriendlyUrlSegments]` attribute uses a zero-indexed map of segments after the page in the URL.  For example, if you request /Hello/foo/bar/... and your page is Hello.aspx, then `[FriendlyUrlSegments(0)]` will map to "foo", `[FriendlyUrlSegments(1)]` will map to "bar", and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you did is model binding not for get information from url.
I read this [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx)

of scott hanselman and i try it. I had the same issue with you. And i thought `[FriendlyUrlSegments]int? id`

for Model binding. Instead of that i did this:

```
var id=Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments()[0];
yourmethod(id);
```

Please feel free to correct me if i'm wrong!
Hope this help.